# Decomposition of finite cyclic group into direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

> Let $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $C_{mn} \cong C_m \times C_n \iff \gcd(m, n) = 1$.

I'm struggling to understand proof of this fact. Can someone explain it step by step?